# Special characters handling with backticks/backquotes in StreamSets Data Collector

Tags: streamsets

My source fields have special characters and need to be enclosed with backticks.

Ex:

```
Source  -   ahj@#
Target  -  ` ahj@# `
```

How do I implement this in StreamSets - enclosing the column names?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to write to MySQL. The correct way to do this is to enable **Enclose Object Names** in the JDBC tab and append `?sessionVariables=sql_mode=ANSI_QUOTES` to the JDBC URL.

Comment: source -  .csv file 
target - hive.. 
trying to use the field renamer in streamsets with below expression 
and getting error "FIELD_RENAMER_00 - Record 'Test2.csv::27' does not contain fields '/'([^a-z A-Z 0-9]*)'' 

Ex:
Field names 
Streamset#,Test!,hive

target should be ~Streamset#~,~Test!~,hive

Source Field Expression : /'([^a-z A-Z 0-9]*)' 
Target Field Expression : /'$1' 

Please suggest how to resolve the issue.